# Passing object from one view to another in django via HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have a "upload" view which creates an instance of a model once a form has been filled-in and considered valid:

```
...
from CrossStitch.models import Pattern

def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newpattern = Pattern(imagefile = request.FILES['pattern'],filename = request.POST['title'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('configure', args=newpattern))
                                                                ^^
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
...
```

As indicated py the up-arrows, I would like to pass the instance of my model to the next view. The configure view is below:

```
def configure(request, pattern):
...
```

both of my views have urls like this:

```
url(r'^upload/$','CrossStitch.views.upload', name='upload'),
url(r'^configure/$','CrossStitch.views.configure', name='configure'),
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError at /CrossStitch/upload/
_reverse_with_prefix() argument after * must be a sequence, not Pattern
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/CrossStitch/upload/
Django Version: 1.4.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
_reverse_with_prefix() argument after * must be a sequence, not Pattern
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in reverse, line 476
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/home/stacey/work/Django/StaceyAnne',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
Server time:    Wed, 4 Sep 2013 15:22:12 +0200
```

How do I pass the instance of my object from one view to another correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `args` keyword argument to `reverse` [is an iterative](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/urlresolvers/). You should pass e.g. a list or a tuple instead.

In your case, however, the `pattern` argument to `configure` shouldn't be an object. In the URL configuration the regex should contain an identifier of a pattern you want to configure, as described in [part 3 of this tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views). This way in `configure` you'd fetch a pattern by its ID, and the `reverse` call would look like this: `reverse('configure', args=[newpattern.id])`.

Comment: I tried that and got "Reverse for 'configure' with arguments '(<Pattern: test>,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found."

Comment: understood. if someone manually types in /configure/<past existing id>, will they be able to see that page?

Comment: This mabye is because your configure view does not accept any arguments, i.e. named regex patterns...

Comment: @StaceyAnne, yes, unless you add some sort of authorisation mechanism. After all, you're just sending a 302 Found HTTP response, which tells the client to send a regular GET request to `/configure/<id>/`.